# How to access android OS through android studio OR from any other Tool.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, operating-system, android-os-handler

I am doing my final year project on detecting and blocking android Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Attacks in WEBVIEW. For that i want to access android Operating System (OS) from where i will detect attacks and block them. Main problem i am facing is **HOW CAN I ACCESS ANDROID OS THROUGH ANDROID STUDIO.? or IS THERE ANY OTHER TOOL FROM WHERE I CAN ACCESS OS.?**

Answer (score 0):

Look for android web view's source code, modify it, and then replace system app. You will probably need root for that.

Comment: Yes i am working on webview. If i root my device then how can i access OS. ?

Comment: Why do you want to modify system?

Comment: actually i want to detect XSS attack in webview by using Artificial algo. So my main idea is that. If i apply algo on OS level from where i will detect attack and block that attack. This is the main reason i want to modify system.

Comment: You want to modify web view, not system. You must find web view's source code, modify it, and replace stock one with yours. Maybe you will need root for this but idk. You can search for other web view app that's easier to modify.